# How to translate from a hexdigest to a digest and vice-versa?

Tags: python, hash, binary-data

I want to store hashes as binary (64 bytes). But for any type of API (web service) I would want to pass them around as strings. `hashlib.hexdigest()` will give me a string, and `hashlib.digest()` will give me the binary. But if, for example, I read in the binary version from disk, how would I convert it to a string? And if I read in the string from a web service, how would I convert it to binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start with the string version to pass around and display:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> string_version = hashlib.md5(b'hello world').hexdigest()
```

Convert it to binary to write it to disk:

```
>>> save_as_binary = string_version.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(save_as_binary)
b'5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3'
```

When reading it back from disk, convert it back to a string:

```
>>> back_to_string = save_as_binary.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(back_to_string)
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3
```

Comment: To clarify: `hashlib.md5(b'hello world').hexdigest().decode('hex') == hashlib.md5(b'hello world').digest()`

Comment: @Ben Thanks alot . This has saved lot of my time. I am working on aws s3 and was trying to figure out how does ETag conversion happens from string->binary->string .. There are lot of answers online but nothing was working for me. But when I tried your answer, it worked just fine. So thank you alotttttt.

Comment: The statement `string_version.encode('utf-8')` does _not_ deliver the binary interpretation of the hexdigest. It just delivers a binary string of the hex string. save_as_binary is not the same as digest() which was asked for.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look into `binascii` module, specifically [`hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) and [`unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) functions.

Comment: Or you can use the built-in [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex).

Answer (score 7):

In 2.x you can use `str.decode('hex')` and `str.encode('hex')` to convert between raw bytes and a hex string. In 3.x you need to use the [`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/binascii.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Some existing answers here are missing the point. The digest is bytes and the hexdigest is a str:

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> h = md5(b"hello world")
>>> h.digest()
b'^\xb6;\xbb\xe0\x1e\xee\xd0\x93\xcb"\xbb\x8fZ\xcd\xc3'
>>> h.hexdigest()
'5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3'
```

Going from digest (bytes) to hexdigest (str), use [`bytes.hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```
>>> h.digest().hex()
'5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3'
```

Going from hexdigest (str) to digest (bytes), use [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(h.hexdigest())
b'^\xb6;\xbb\xe0\x1e\xee\xd0\x93\xcb"\xbb\x8fZ\xcd\xc3'
```